# How to add child layouts in a Custom built layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created some xml layouts. Now I am creating a custom layout (in my java file) with some elements and want to add the previously created layout(xml layouts). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LayoutInflater` to inlate layouts. And add inflated view to your custom view by `addView()` method

For ex:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
ViewGroup viewTobeLoaded = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ilan_list_item, null);
yourView.addView(viewTobeLoaded);
```

Hope helps

Comment: Can you please tell me if the layout (ilan_list_item) contains a listview, then how can we set our custom built adapter for this ListView? basically I want to access the elements of this child view.

Comment: After inflating the view simply use 
ListView yourListView=(ListView)viewTobeLoaded.findViewById(R.id.yourListViewId);
And then set your adapter as usually, yourListView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);

Comment: Thanks for the reply Murat. I have another problem in which the on the listView I have added an onclick listener. Each listView item is a relative layout having 3 elements(a textView and a imageview). by using listview.getChildAt(position), I can get the listitem, but I want to set textview to some other value. how can I do that?

Comment: In your adapter's getView method you can use TextView yourTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(YourTextViewId); and then with yourTextView.setText("Text") method you can change the text of textview. If my answers are helped you, please mark my question as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<include>` tag in your new layout. See [docs here.](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html)